# Accessing parameters in parent state

Tags: angularjs

I have the following setup in my AngularJS app:

```
.state('people.view',
{
    abstract: true,
    parent: 'people',
    views: {
        'header@maincontent': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/people/_header_view.html'
        },
        'footer@maincontent': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/people/_footer_view.html'
        }
    }
})
    .state('people.details',
    {
        parent: 'people.view',
        url: '/:personId/details',
        views: {
            'content@maincontent': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/people/details.html',
                controller: 'PeopleDetailCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('people.addressbook',
    {
        parent: 'people.view',
        url: '/:personId/addressbook',
        views: {
            'content@maincontent': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/people/addressbook.html',
                controller: 'PeopleAddressBookCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

So I have a Detail and an Address Book view that are children of a Person View state that has a header and footer (that don't change).

But because the `personId` is only passed in the child states and only they have a controller specified, then it means I can't access the person information.

For example in the header I want to show the person name.

How can I do this?

---

Based on the answer below from @mohamedrias I have tried:

```
.controller('PeopleDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'Person',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, Person) {
        $scope.person = Person.get({personId: $stateParams.personId}, function(person) {        
            console.log(person);
            $rootScope.person.firstname = person.firstname;
            $rootScope.person.lastname = person.lastname;
        });

    }]);
```

So that I can access `{{person.firstname}}` in the header, but I get the error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstname' of undefined`

The console shows:

`Resource {firstname: "Cameron", lastname: "Drysdale", $promise: Object, $resolved: true, $get: function…}`

Comment: you can either attach it to $rootScope / use $scope.$emit for emitting the value from child controller and listen to it in parent controller using $scope.$on

Comment: @mohamedrias Can you please provide an answer / example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child controller, emit the event along with personId.

```
$scope.$emit('personId', personId);
```

In your parent controller:

```
$scope.$on('personId', function(event, personId) {
      // check for personId and process the information
});
```

The above is nice way of doing it.

Else you can do in normal way too, but it's not recommended.

Inject `$rootScope` in your child controller:

```
app.controller("ChildController", function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.personId = $routeParams.personId;
});
```

In your template header, you can just refer to `personId` and it will pick the value from `$rootScope`.

Update based on your code:

```
$rootScope.person = $rootScope.person || {};
$rootScope.person.firstname = person.firstname;
```

This is just to make sure that `$rootScope.person` is available.

Comment: So I have to have a parent controller for the header then?

Comment: Not really, inside your `run` method also you can bind event using `$rootScope.$on` instead of the parent controller. It will work perfectly. Better you just add the personId to the $rootScope which will be available in the header. But if there is more interaction between the parentCtrl and childCtrl then setting up a dedicated parent controller would be good

Comment: you must instantiate person before. it must be like `$rootScope.person = $rootScope.person || {};` and then append `$rootScope.person.personId = "value";`